# scrollIntoView in not working, why? and how to fixed?

Tags: javascript

How can I make this code work? I'm getting errors

//scroll to section
this part is to get all the

```
const linkes = document.querySelectorAll('a')

linkes.forEach(link => {

  link.addEventListener('click', toSection())

})
```

this part is to build the function for scrollIntoView

```
function toSection() {

  sections.forEach(section => {

    const sectionsIds = section.id

  })

 sectionsIds.scrollIntoView();

}
```

Comment: Do you want each `a` to scroll to a specific section on click? If thats the case, just use `<a href="#sectionID"></a>` and `<section id='''sectionID'></section>`

Comment: correct! that's what the code should do

Comment: `link.addEventListener('click', toSection())` should be passing `toSection` instead of `toSection()`, because you don't want to execute the function there, but rather pass the function as a reference. Also [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on a `NodeList` doesn't work on every browser. That being said, what is `sections`? Why do you use a `forEach` there? To which element of the collection do you expect to scroll to? Also what is the goal of the `ìd`? You can't call `scrollIntoView()` on a string.

Comment: Sections is a constant where I put each section.  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section') I did it to create a dynamic navigation menu

Comment: @Imcoding Is there only 1 `section`? If so, then use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` and remove the loop.

Comment: like this:  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

Comment: const list = `<li><a class="links_menu" href="#${sections[i].id}"></a>${sections[i].dataset.name}</li>`;
    manyList += list;

Comment: }
//list is add it to the nav
nav.innerHTML = manyList;

Comment: I have many sections. 4 in total

Comment: Thanks! I found here one of the problems,It should looks like this: <li><a class="links_menu" href="#${sections[i].id}">${sections[i].dataset.name}</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<a data-myattr="myScrollSection1">to section 1</a>
<a data-myattr="myScrollSection2">to section 2</a>
<div id="myScrollSection1">Section1</div>
<div id="myScrollSection2">Section2</div>

<script>
  const links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      myId = e.target.dataset.myattr;
      console.log(myId);
      document.getElementById(myId).scrollIntoView();
    });
  }
</script>
```